# どうして「お聞き遊ばして」が現代語訳では「お吸いなさいまして」になるのか分からない

Tags: keigo, classical-japanese

[現代訳](http://p.booklog.jp/book/26987/read)を頼りに、泉鏡花さんの[「外科室」](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000050/files/360_19397.html)を読もうとしているところですが、分からない箇所があります。

原文の

> 看護婦は医学士の旨を領してのち、かの腰元に立ち向かいて、
>   「もう、なんですから、あのことを、ちょっと、あなたから」
>   　腰元はその意を得て、手術台に擦り寄りつ、優に膝のあたりまで両手を下げて、しとやかに立礼し、
>   **「夫人、ただいま、お薬を差し上げます。どうぞそれを、*お聞きあそばして*、いろはでも、数字でも、お算えあそばしますように」**
>   　伯爵夫人は答なし。

は現代訳ではこうなる。

> 看護婦は医学士の指示を承知した後、あの侍女に向かって、
>   「もう、時間ですから、あのことを、ちょっと、あなたから申し上げてください」
>   　侍女はその言葉の意味を理解して、手術台に擦り寄り、膝のあたりまで両手を下げて、しとやかに深く立礼し、
>   **「奥様、ただいま、お薬を差し上げます。どうぞそれを、*お吸いなさいまして*、いろはでも、数字でも、お数えなさいますように」**
>   　伯爵夫人の答えはない。

---

「お聞きあそばして」を見た時に、「お聞きなさいまして」と解釈したが、現代訳によると、「お聞きなさいまして」ではなく、「お吸いなさいまして」という意味だそうです。理由は何ですか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

明鏡国語辞典によりますと、「聞く」の意味として、

> きく
>   ⑤[聞]においをかぐ。また、においのよしあしなどを感じとる。「[香]{こう}を聞く」
>   ⑥[聞]酒の良しあしなどを舌で感じとる。「酒を聞く」
>   表記 ⑥は「利く」とも。

とあります。どんなお薬なのか（飲み薬ではない？）、先を読めばわかるかもしれませんが、この場合、５の意味として解釈されているのだと思います。少し古いような、硬い感じの表現なので、現代語訳では「吸う」にされているのだと思います。

Comment: 吸入麻酔薬ですね。時代的にジエチルエーテルでしょうか。数を数えさせるのは意識が消失したことがわかるようにです。

Comment: ^ おお～～！　なるとはん、さすが～～

Comment: まさか、このの意味もありましたか。ありがとうございました。